# complicate regex passing

Tags: python

I have a table df with the following column 'txt' in the string format. For example,

---

### -- this is the first record

cloudy

BB - continually 53, continual 26, daily 7, always 6, alway 4, ever 3,
perpetual 2, continual employment 1, evermore 1, never 1; 104

1 cloudy

---

### -- this is the second record

sunny

BB - Akkub 8; 8

extra strings here

1 sunny

---

### -- this is the third record

rainy

BB - Hezekiah 85, Hizkiah 1, Hizkijah 1; 87

extra strings here

1 rainy

---

I want to use regex to pass the string after 'BB - ' but only till the last number after BB. For example the first record I will be:
***BB - continually 53, continual 26, daily 7, always 6, alway 4, ever 3, perpetual 2, continual employment 1, evermore 1, never 1; 104***

the 2nd record will be:
***BB - Akkub 8; 8***

the 3rd record will be:
***BB - Hezekiah 85, Hizkiah 1, Hizkijah 1; 87***

Initially, I tried the following code

```
df['txt_parse'] = df['txt']\
                  .apply(lambda x: " ".join(w.strip() for w in re.findall(r'BB - (.*?)\r\n', x)))\
                  .str.split(';').str.get(0).str.split(', ')
```

but the problem is that in the first record between "3" and "perpetual" there is a /n, so it only parse string till "ever 3," instead of "never 1; 104".

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the separator you're looking for? Is it newlines? `but only till the last number after BB` doesn't make much sense to me because there's more numbers after what you said is the expected output. E.g. `1 cloudy` and `1 rainy`. The only thing before the end of the expected result is whitespace. Is the semicolon significant?

Comment: ```re.compile(r'(?s)(?=BB)(.+)(?<=\d(?=.?\n))')```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
a = """cloudy

BB - continually 53, continual 26, daily 7, always 6, alway 4, ever 3,
perpetual 2, continual employment 1, evermore 1, never 1; 104

1 cloudy"""

b = """sunny

BB - Akkub 8; 8

extra strings here

1 sunny"""

c = """rainy

BB - Hezekiah 85, Hizkiah 1, Hizkijah 1; 87

extra strings here

1 rainy"""

r = re.compile(r'(?s)(?=BB)(.+)(?<=\d(?=.?\n))')

for i in (a, b, c):
    s = r.search(i).group()
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
BB - continually 53, continual 26, daily 7, always 6, alway 4, ever 3,
perpetual 2, continual employment 1, evermore 1, never 1; 104
BB - Akkub 8; 8
BB - Hezekiah 85, Hizkiah 1, Hizkijah 1; 87
```

Edit: added an extra `\n`.

Comment: I think you removed a newline from the first case. OP stated: `but the problem is that in the first record between "3" and "perpetual" there is a /n, so it only parse string till "ever 3," instead of "never 1; 104".`

Comment: thanks, that is awesome. I never used "?=" and "?<=", how to change the regex to only extra the part after "BB - "?

Comment: ```re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=BB\s-\s)(.+)(?<=\d(?=(\D*)?\n))')```.